# how to change the check frequency of an egalax touchscreen

Tags: raspberry-pi, hardware, raspbian, touchscreen

I have an egalax resistive touchscreen, it works in a normal way, but if I touch it rapidly,  for example, just lie it down and drop down a pen on it, it just no response.

I guess it maybe needs to adjust the check frequency to a high value, so that can notice the instantaneous touch (hit).

so, how to make it work in a high check frequency way?

Answer (score 0):

You can install xinput_calibrator :
apt-get install libts-bin

This will create a configuration file called /etc/ts.conf, which contains settings like debounce and lowpass filter settings.

You can check parameters manual at the [man page](https://www.mankier.com/5/ts.conf)

Comment: thanks,i will test that later, but the debounce parameter in manual said, the default value is 0, is that mean "there is no debounce"? in that case, in my case, i need the debounce is more less more better(senstive)

Comment: i installed libts-bin and checked the manual, and added a new line "module_raw galax“ in ts.conf, cause i used a eGalax touchscreen，and set the "module debounce drop_threshold=0" and "module dejitter delta=0" , how make this modifed conf file effect? need restart some service? cause it looks nothin changed even i saved ts.conf with new settings

Comment: Try 
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb1

Then just do ts_calibrate and/or ts_test

Comment: yes,i tested with ts_calibrate,however, the touchscreen is still not emit event when did instantaneous hit, is that the hardware's limit? or what is the correct way to set ts.conf to support this situation?